# link with class name to target div with an id same as the class name of the link

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a list of links with class names and a container with divs which ids are the same as the class names of the links.

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="table-names">Names</a></li>
  <li><a class="table-addresses">Addresses</a></li>
  <li><a class="table-phone">Phone Numbers</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div id="table-names" class="selected">...</div>
  <div id="table-addresses">...</div>
  <div id="table-phone">...</div>
</div>
```

If I click on the link "table-names" then `id="table-names"` needs to have the class `selected` added, and the siblings need to have the class "selected" removed.

Here's my jquery:

```
$('ul li a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass("selected").siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
    $('.container div').removeClass("selected");
    $('#' + $(this).className()).addClass("selected");
});
```

This is somehow not working although I believe the code is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `$(this).attr('class')` are you sure there is only one class in the anchor

Comment: Thank you, yes of course I didn't think of this.

Comment: glad to help mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).className()` is not valid, you need to change it to `$(this).attr('class')` or `this.className`

```
$('ul li a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass("selected").siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
    $('.container div').removeClass("selected");
    $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick :) weird, I think I saw className used somewhere. But this worked so thank you.

Comment: @WimMertens - you're welcome. `className` is a property of a native DOM element, not a jQuery function, so it's either `this.className` or `$(this).attr('class')`

Answer (score 0):

className is is not a jquery method

```
var target = document.getElementById("table-names");
alert(target.className) //not className()
```

To get class in jquery, use attr("class"), attr() method can be used to get or set any attribute...

```
var $use = $(this).attr("class");
$("#"+$use).siblings().removeClass("selected")
```

I hope this helps